# How to get one value from Hashmap to intent without using textview?

Tags: android, android-intent, hashmap

I retrieve few data from database then store it into hashmap  and display it on listview.

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(TAG_NAME, name);
            map.put(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
            map.put(TAG_VID, vid);
            venueList.add(map);
```

This is the value i wanna past to another page.

```
@Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting values from selected ListItem
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
            String address = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.address)).getText().toString();
            String vid = "NEED HELP HERE"

            // Starting new intent
            Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
            in.putExtra(TAG_NAME, name);
            in.putExtra(TAG_ADDRESS, address);
            in.putExtra(TAG_VID, vid);
            startActivity(in);
        }
```

I manage to pass the value which are display on TextView, but how do i pass the VID which are not TextView??

```
String vid = getListAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
```

I tried this but it show all the data. How do i select one particular VID??

Thanks.

Comment: What is a VID in the context of your question?

Comment: maybe instead of adding the values to a hashmap you can ad them to a String Vector so you can search for the position of string on your list view, and the use this position to get the data from the String Vector

Comment: instead of using hashmap, just use `Bundle` which will be easy to pass to next activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put vid into bundle directly from map

```
in.putExtra(TAG_VID, map.get(TAG_VID));
```

Comment: make your **map** as a global object. else paste your code so i can suggest any other possibility

Comment: Thanks Waqas,
It work with this code.
`HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
             map = (HashMap<String, String>) getListAdapter().getItem(position);`